# Python returns "invalid syntax" with Jinja2 set tag

Tags: python, jinja2

I have version 2.11.2 of Jinja2 installed.

```
~]$ pip3 list
Package                            Version
---------------------------------- ------------------
Jinja2                             2.11.2
```

And version 3.6.8 of Python

```
~]$ python --version
Python 3.6.8
```

I've a Python script named test.py. Here is the content of test.py.

```
from jinja2 import Template
name = "John Doe"
template = Template("Hello {{ name }}")
message = template.render(name=name)
print(message)
```

Invoking test.py is successful, "John Doe" is returned.

```
~]# python test.py
John Doe
```

I update test.py to have the following.

```
import jinja2
{% set foo = 'bar' %}
```

When I invoke test.py, I get "invalid syntax".

```
~]$ python test.py
  File "testing.py", line 4
    {% set foo = 'bar' %}
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Best I can tell, I am using a valid syntax for the set tag, thus I'm not sure how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `test.py` is file executed by Python and not the template file interpreted by Jinja. Python interpreter has no idea how to interpret `{% set foo = 'bar' %}`.

Usually your code (`test.py`) needs to load template in Jinja format from file (e.g. `test.j2`) and then interpret it using Jinja API. Here is very simple example:

test.py (Python code):

```py
from jinja2 import Template
name = "John Doe"
template = Template(open('test.j2').read()) # Read template from file test.j2
print(template.render(name=name))
```

test.j2 (template, in same directory from where you run code):

```
Hello {{ name }}
{% set foo = 'bar' %}
```

Note the code above is not ideal (just generally demonstrates how Jinja works) and you should consult https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/ and eventually https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#loaders on how to properly load templates and render them from your code.

Comment: Awesome, this makes sense. Thanks much. Indeed, this code is rough, as Python is not my fortay. I've only happened to have a need to better understand Python and Jinja2 when debugging some Python/Jinja2 related issue with our Ansible playbooks, as Ansible uses Python and Jinja2.

Answer (score 0):

`{% set foo = 'bar' %}` is not a valid python code but you use it inside `test.py`. It maybe a valid jinja2 code but you are mixing python and jinja2 here..